# fadeIn() in a variable jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, fadein

I (i'll try) explain my problem :p
I want to use a variable javascript with php like this:

```
var Effet = '$effet';
```

this return: an effet for jquery, exemple: fadeIn

Later in js file, i want to apply the effect on element.

I tryed:

```
$('div#something').hide().append(data).Effet+'(1000)';
```

But this doesn't work... i can't get fadein(1000);

Any idea?

Thx for response

PS: Thx to all contributors and creators of this website, really nice job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var Effect = "fadeIn", data="things";
$('div#something').hide().append(data)[Effect](1000);
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/UTYgb/1/), in JavaScript these are equivalent:

```
object.propOrFunctionName
object["propOrFunctionName"]
```

Comment: Work very well!
Thx, this is exacly what i search :)